# Calendar gives error for Gmail Account: 403 CalDAVAccountRefreshQueueableOperation

Tags: macos, calendar, google

Recently I started getting errors from Calendar.app about my synced Gmail calendars. I haven't made any changes to my Gmail security settings.

Usually if Google needs to be authenticated for macOS apps it pops up a little portal window asking me to sign in. I haven't been able to trigger this window to popup.

It seems that at least one of my calendars is still syncing between Calendar.app and Google Calendar in both directions. All calendars are on the same account.

Just in case this is relevant, I recently (2-ish weeks ago) upgraded a different mac on my apple id to Mojave.

Update:
I have cleared the iCal cache as per [google support](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/54852740?hl=en&msgid=54852740) advice, as well as revoked [authorization from google](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) and re-authorized as per this [recent thread](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/98473879?hl=en) on google support forum. The issue still remains.

macOS 10.10.5

```
 The server responded:
“403”
to operation CalDAVAccountRefreshQueueableOperation.
```

[image]

[Google Support](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/98473879) thread for this issue.

[Apple Discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252441405) thread for this issue.

Comment: Having the same problem on Big Sur.

Comment: I have the same problems for several days. I'm using Big Sur 11.2.1 and my Calendar app is 11.0 (2811.3.1) Even one day, I spent three hour trying to fix it. I have tried to delete Calendar cache files, restart my MacBook Pro several times, login with another google account, delete google account and re-add it in system, use different networks, revoke macOS authorization and grant it, balabala.... Finally, it worked by itself after several hours. But today, the problem encountered again. I will not waste my time on this problem, waiting for an update to fix this problem by Google or Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. I'm also operating Yosemite (10.10.5)

Saw the solution below for Sierra elsewhere, but it didn't work for me.

+++++++++

This problem appears to be caused by corrupted Calendar caches and it occurs in macOS 10.12.2 Sierra as well.

The easiest way to get rid of this problem is to:

Quit Calendar

Open Activity Viewer and Quit "CalendarAgent"

note, using QuickLook on any calendar item in the Finder will

relaunch CalendarAgent which needs to be not running at step 3

Delete ~/Library/Calendars/Calendar Cache

Delete ~/Library/Calendars/Calendar Cache-shm

Delete ~/Library/Calendars/Calendar Cache-wal

Launch Calendar

Calendar will read the information from the surrounding data folders and files in ~/Library/Calendars/ and recreate the caches cleanly.

If for some reason the files listed to delete re-appear before you launch Calendar, it means something is triggering the system calendar operations. Try quitting all of your applications and starting at step 2 or logging out with the "Reopen windows when logging back in" unchecked, then logging back in.

++++++++

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a shot and although it successfully rebuilt my calendars, I’m still receiving the error.

Comment: This does not work, and, OP already stated that he had done it it and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Hello John,

He said he’d cleared the cache, but didn’t specify what steps he’d taken to do it.
The poster previous to you and I both indicated that it didn’t work for us. What new information is your post providing?